# Can I know what applications are opened without using activityManager in android?

Tags: android

Are there any ways that I can know what applications are opened without using activityManager ?

I want to record how many times each applications are opened. for example, when user open the web browser, the counter of web browser will be increased 1. I can do that by creating a thread and using activityManager; however, if I want to use the thread to listen the event, it may waste a lots battery power!? So, can I use something like intent/broadcast receiver or else?

Answer (score 0):

you can use UsageStatsService, its a framework service. that contains all these infos.